# Como escrever e ler uma table hash em/de um arquivo (FILE) em C?

Tags: c, hash

Estou usando fread e fwrite mas ocorre um erro de execução.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct pessoa{
   char nome[20];
   char cpf[10];
   struct pessoa* next;
}Pessoa;

typedef struct lista{
   Pessoa* head;
}lista;

typedef struct hash{
   int qtd,table_size;
   lista** itens;
}Hash;

void imprimirHash(Hash ha){
  int i;
  Pessoa* aux;
  printf("==========================\n");
  for(i=0;i<ha.table_size;i++){
    if(ha.itens[i]!=NULL){
        aux = ha.itens[i]->head;
        while(aux!=NULL){
            printf("Nome: %s\n",aux->nome);
            printf("Cpf: %s\n",aux->cpf);
            aux = aux->next;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}

void lerPessoa(Pessoa* pes){
   printf("Digite o nome: ");
   scanf("%s",pes->nome);
   printf("Digite o cpf: ");
   scanf("%s",pes->cpf);
}

Hash* criaHash(int table_size){
   Hash* ha;
   ha = (Hash *)malloc(sizeof(Hash));
   if(ha){
    int i;
    ha->table_size = table_size;
    ha->itens = (lista**)malloc(table_size * sizeof(lista*));
    if(!ha->itens){
        free(ha);
        return NULL;
    }
    ha->qtd = 0;
    for(i=0;i < ha->table_size; i++){
        ha->itens[i] = NULL;
    }
 }
  return ha;
}

void liberaHash(Hash* ha){
   if(ha){
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < ha->table_size; i++){
        if(ha->itens[i]){
            free(ha->itens[i]);
        }
    }
    free(ha->itens);
    free(ha);
 }
}

int chaveDivisao(int chave, int table_size){
   return(chave & 0x7FFFFFFF) % table_size;
}

int valorString(char *str){
   int i, valor = 7;
   int tam = strlen(str);
   for(i=0; i<tam; i++){
      valor = 31 * valor + (int)str[i];
   }
  return valor;
}

int insereHash(Hash *ha, Pessoa* pes){
   if(!ha || ha->qtd == ha->table_size){
     return 0;
   }
  //int chave = al.matricula;
    int chave = valorString(pes->nome);
    int pos = chaveDivisao(chave, ha->table_size);
    printf("\nvalor do hash de %s eh %d e a posicao no vetor eh: %d\n",pes-      >nome, chave,pos);
   lista** aux;
   aux = (lista**)malloc(sizeof(lista*));
   //lista *novo;
   (*aux) = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
   printf("{add:: %d}",&(*aux));
   if(!(*aux)){
    return 0;
   }
   (*aux)->head = pes;
   if(ha->itens[pos]!=NULL){
    (*aux)->head->next = ha->itens[pos]->head;
    ha->itens[pos] = (*aux);
    printf("\nproximo\n"); 
  } else {
    ha->itens[pos] = (*aux);
    (*aux)->head->next = NULL;
    printf("\nprimeiro\n");
 }
  ha->qtd++;
  return 1;
}

int buscaHash(Hash* ha, char *str, Pessoa* pes){
   Pessoa* aux;
if(!ha){
    return 0;
}
int chave = valorString(str);
int pos = chaveDivisao(chave,ha->table_size);
if(ha->itens[pos]!=NULL){
    aux = ha->itens[pos]->head;
    do{
        if(strcmp(str,aux->nome)==0){
            *pes = *aux;
            return 1;
        } else{
            aux = aux->next;
        }
    }while(aux!=NULL);
}
 return 0;
}

void deletarItem(Hash* ha, char *str){
  Pessoa aux;
  if(buscaHash(ha,str,&aux)){
    int chave = valorString(str);
    int pos = chaveDivisao(chave,ha->table_size);
    if(ha->itens[pos]->head->next==NULL){
        ha->itens[pos] = NULL;
    } else{
        ha->itens[pos]->head = ha->itens[pos]->head->next;
    }
 } 
}

main(){
  Hash* password;
  FILE *f;
  Pessoa uendel,aux;
  int i;
  f = fopen("testes.txt","a+");
  password = criaHash(23);
  //fread(&password,sizeof(Hash*),1,f);
  ///*
    lerPessoa(&uendel);
    insereHash(password,&uendel);
    lerPessoa(&aux);
    insereHash(password,&aux);
    printf("Tamnho == %d\n",password->qtd);
    printf("{%d}",buscaHash(password,aux.nome,&aux));
  //*/
  imprimirHash(*password);
  //fwrite(&password,sizeof(Hash*),1,f);
  fclose(f);
  liberaHash(password); 
}
```

Comment: Primeiramente, qual o erro de execução? Explique mais sobre o seu problema, por favor.